# What kind of loop bug does this code have and how to fix it?

Tags: java, loops, boolean

Just wondering where exactly is the bug? Is the for statement formatted incorrectly?

```
int n; 
sum = 0; 
for (n = 1; n < 10; n++) {
  sum = sum + n;
System.out.println("1 + 2 + ...+ 9 + 10 == " + sum);
```

Comment: try int sum = 0; instead of sum = 0; & close the '{' bracket for the for loop

Comment: If this is Java then this code has compilation errors not bugs. And if you try to compile it or copy paste this code to any Java IDE you will instantly know all compilations errors.

Comment: The code would sum numbers 1-9, not 1-10, if compilation errors are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your for loop with a `}` and declare the sum variable as an int. So the code should look like:

```
int n; 
int sum = 0; 
for (n = 1; n < 10; n++){
    sum = sum + n;
}
System.out.println("1 + 2 + ...+ 9 + 10 == " + sum);
```

You should research using an IDE like Eclipse. Its a text editor for your code that will point out where the compilation errors are.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. What if we were given ++ instead of n++, what type of loop bug is that?